# Order By based on number of LIKE occurences Laravel Php

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I have a simple search engine on my site

I'm trying to match the `keyword` in all fields.

Here's the simplified working codes

```
$keyword_search = "Hello World";
$delimeter = ' '; //or your separator
$keywords = explode($delimeter, $keyword_search); 

$base_query = \App\Models\EntireSearchSite::where('id','!=',NULL);

foreach($keywords as $keyword){
    $base_query->where(function($query) use ($keyword){
            $query->where('part_number', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%') 
                ->orWhere('part_name', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
                ->orWhere('category', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
                ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%');
    });
    
}

$data = $base_query->paginate(20);
return $data;
```

What I'm trying to do is to match all keyword, count all matched keyword (for every occurences) and do `Order By Desc` from highest occurences to lowest.

If I enter `"Hello World"`

it will find all the data that will match to `"Hello World"`

I got `part_number, part_name, category, description` fields

it will sum the total number of occurrences on all fields and arrange the `ORDER BY` from highest to lowest (DESC)

EXAMPLE:

DATA #1

number of matched keyword in `part_number` is 0

number of matched keyword in `part_name` is 2

number of matched keyword in `category` is 0

number of matched keyword in `description` is 0

TOTAL = 2

DATA #2

number of matched keyword in `part_number` is 0

number of matched keyword in `part_name` is 0

number of matched keyword in `category` is 2

number of matched keyword in `description` is 10

TOTAL = 12

DATA #3

number of matched keyword in `part_number` is 0

number of matched keyword in `part_name` is 0

number of matched keyword in `category` is 0

number of matched keyword in `description` is 5

TOTAL = 5

and order by desc should be something like this

DATA#2

DATA#3

DATA#1

**UPDATE***

Tried the answer from @Anas

```
$delimeter = ' '; //or your separator
$keywords = explode($delimeter, $keyword_search); 

$base_query = \App\Models\EntireSearchSite::where('id','!=',NULL);

foreach($keywords as $keyword){
    $base_query->where(function($query) use ($keyword){
            $query->where('part_number', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%') 
                ->orWhere('part_name', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
                ->orWhere('category', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
                ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%');
    });
}

foreach($keywords as $keyword){
            $base_query->selectRaw(function($querySelect) use ($keyword){
                $querySelect->selectRaw('
                    Round ((Char_length(Concat(
                        part_number, 
                        part_name,
                        category,
                        description

                    )) - Char_length(REPLACE ( Concat(
                        part_number, 
                        part_name,
                        category,
                        description
                    ), "'.$keyword.'", ""))) / Char_length("'.$keyword.'"))  AS count 
                ');

            });
}        

$data = $base_query->orderBy('count','DESC')->paginate(20);
return $data;
```

But I'm getting undefined column count

**Update**

Applied answer by @Donkarnash

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not quite what you're looking for, but have a look at match against: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-full-text-search-functions.php

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to concat related column in one string then get total number of occurrences by this query sample. also you can use in select DB:raw() [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions)

```sql
SELECT email, 
       name, 
       Round ((Char_length(Concat(email, name)) - Char_length(REPLACE ( Concat(email,name), "anas", ""))) / Char_length("anas")) AS count 
FROM   users
Having count >0 
ORDER  BY count DESC;
```

Result of query

[image: Result of Query]

For sperate Keyword you can sum new Round function with different keyword check this query

```sql
SELECT email, 
       name, 
       Round ((Char_length(Concat(email, name)) - Char_length(REPLACE ( Concat(email,name), "first_keyword", ""))) / Char_length("first_keyword")) 
       + Round ((Char_length(Concat(email, name)) - Char_length(REPLACE ( Concat(email,name), "second_keyword", ""))) / Char_length("second_keyword"))  AS count 
FROM   users
Having count >0 
ORDER  BY count DESC;
```

To make it case insensitive you can convert keywords and columns to lower case
Ex:

```sql
 SELECT email,
        name,
    Round ((lower(Char_length(Concat(email, name))) - Char_length(REPLACE ( lower(Concat(email,name)), lower("aasd"), ""))) / Char_length(lower("aasd"))) AS count 
    FROM   users 
    Having count >0 ORDER  BY count DESC;
```

Comment: this is good but, the keyword should not be case sensitive whether the word is capitalized or not as long as it's the same word. it only counts "anas" but when I tried "Anas" it doesn't count "Anas" where it should count it too.

Comment: I think im pretty close, I can get the count data based from your code. But I have this additional field called `page_content` data type is `TEXT` Where it contains some html code. like `<p> Lorem sum</p> <h3>Lorem Sum</h3>` when I tried to add this field on query, query doesn't seems to be working

Comment: What is the error when you are using page_content field

Comment: it doesnt return any data when page_content field is added. this field sometimes contains some value of html sometimes it just null. maybe because some records are null or maybe because it cannot count the value of field if the value contains html codes.

Answer (score 4):

Since using the `selectRaw` in a loop, the alias of the count operation should not be `count` (repeating for all iterations of loop). Rather it should be `'count'.$keyword` to make it a unique alias.

Similarly the `orderBy()` should also be defined within the loop so as to orderBy the `'count'.$keyword` columns.

```php
$base_query = \App\Models\EntireSearchSite::where('id','!=',NULL);

foreach($keywords as $keyword){
    $base_query->where(function($query) use ($keyword){
        $query->where('part_number', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%') 
            ->orWhere('part_name', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
            ->orWhere('category', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
            ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%');
    });
}

foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
    $base_query->selectRaw('
        Round (
            (Char_length(Concat(email, name)) - Char_length(REPLACE ( Concat(email,name), "' . $keyword .'", ""))
        ) / Char_length("' . $keyword .'")
        ) AS count' .  $keyword
    )
    ->orderBy("count$keyword", "desc");
}

$data = $base_query->paginate(20);
return $data;
```

Comment: Hello, tried to do this but got `Object of class Closure could not be converted to string` is it because on my fields' data type?

Comment: Can you find in the stack trace which line of code causes the error. Cause I tried as per @anas's example of users table and it works flawlessly with two keywords

Comment: Probably there would be a detailed entry in the log file at `sotrage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: I updated my post to see the error,I have 10 remaining fields that I didn't include here on the codes just the part_number, part_name, category, description. is it necessary?

Comment: will check on that

Comment: Have updated the answer, guess the outer `selectRaw` was causing the error in the second foreach loop - try the updated one

Comment: Just for your info, you can use a full text search and get the score as percentage of match - if that serves your purpose

Comment: @RaeIan "I have 10 remaining fields that I didn't include here on the codes" - every like "%$term%" search has performance cost as it can't use any index - beware. If you have multiple columns to search against using **like** operator normalisation as virtual columns help or better yet would be to define a full search index with multiple columns on the table

Answer (score 0):

You can select all related raws and then sort them in your controller.
Please note that complex queries take a lot of time to complete. In my opinion, you can select your data and then count the match keywords by using `strpos` function.

````php
foreach($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
 foreach($keywords as $keyword)
 {
   if (strpos($data[$i]->partition, $keyword) !== false) {
    $counter = $counter+1; 
  .
  .
  .
  .

  }
 }
  $final[$i] = [
  'data'=>$data[$i],
  'priority'=>$counter
];
}
then you can sort it by ```arsort()``` based on priority
````